# getting all listings using GetSellerList

Tags: php, ebay-api

Currently I'm working eBay Trading APIs.
I want to get all active listings but getting 194.
I have 2269 active listings in my seller account.
here is my code.

```
$curl_resource = $this->initialize_requests("GetSellerList", false);
        $xmlStr="<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>
<GetSellerListRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>".$this->userToken."</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
  <GranularityLevel>Coarse</GranularityLevel>
  <StartTimeFrom>2017-06-21T06:38:48.420Z</StartTimeFrom> 
  <StartTimeTo>2017-08-23T06:38:48.420Z</StartTimeTo> 
  <IncludeWatchCount>true</IncludeWatchCount> 
  <Pagination> 
    <EntriesPerPage>50</EntriesPerPage> 
  </Pagination>
</GetSellerListRequest>";
        $response = $this->getResponse($curl_resource, $xmlStr);
        $responseObject = simplexml_load_string($response);
        print_r($responseObject);
```

I think I should change `<startTimeFrom>` and `<startTimeTo>` after every call until it return null or something.
or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass page number in you XML feed,because eBay API returns only 200 listings per page so you need to loop through the API call.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetMyeBaySellingRequest
    xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <RequesterCredentials>
        <eBayAuthToken>$this->auth_token</eBayAuthToken>
    </RequesterCredentials>
    <ActiveList>
        <Sort>Title</Sort>
        <IncludeNotes>FALSE</IncludeNotes>
        <Pagination>
            <EntriesPerPage>200</EntriesPerPage>
            <PageNumber>$page_no</PageNumber>
        </Pagination>
    </ActiveList>
    <HideVariations>FALSE</HideVariations>
    <DetailLevel>ReturnSummary</DetailLevel>
    <MessageID>$messageID</MessageID>
    <Version>$this->api_version</Version>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
</GetMyeBaySellingRequest>​
```

Answer (score 1):

eBay returns 200 entries as a response in a single call, so you need to loop through the same call by passing the PageNumber element in the Pagination index while creating an XML.

Comment: have you got your solution?

Comment: yeah.. I got solution.